# SendKeys lasting too long (C# Selenium geckodriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to send keys (a string of 1000 lines) to a textarea using Selenium for Firefox in C#, but Selenium freezes for a minute, and after that, an error appears but the text appears written on the textarea.

This is the error:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out
>   after 60 seconds

What can it be?

Thank you,

---

Edit

```
String text;
IWebElement textarea;

try
{
    textarea.Clear();
    textarea.SendKeys(text); //Here's where it freezes for 60 seconds.
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //After those 60 seconds, the aforementioned error appears.
}

//And finally, after another 30 seconds, the text appears written on the textarea.
```

`text` and `textarea` represent some real values, which are correct (the element is present, etc)

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_? Can you update the question with your _code trials_?

Comment: Yeah sure, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because the driver doesn't respond within 60 seconds, probably because `SendKeys` is taking more than 60 seconds to simulate all keys.

Either split your text into smaller strings and call `SendKeys` for each one of them:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ToChunks(string text, int chunkLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chunkLength; i += chunkLength)
        yield return text.Substring(i, Math.Min(chunkLength, text.Length - i));
}


foreach (string chunk in ToChunks(text, 256))
    textarea.SendKeys(chunk);
```

Or simulate a text insertion from a user (paste from clipboard or drop).
This use case is not directly supported by Selenium, so you'll have to use a script injection:

```
string JS_INSERT_TEXT = @"
    var text = arguments[0];
    var target = window.document.activeElement;

    if (!target || target.tagName !== 'INPUT' && target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA')
      throw new Error('Expected an <input> or <textarea> as active element');

    window.document.execCommand('inserttext', false, text);
    ";

textarea.Clear();
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(JS_INSERT_TEXT, text);
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution to my problem. I can't test it today so I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @AsierAzkolain You can also paste/copy text without using JS by utilizing the Clipboard class built into C#, and I believe that better simulates a user pasting text (as it actually is pasting text)

Comment: @Rescis, yes setting the text in the clipboard and calling Keys.Control + "v" is an option. Although I tend to avoid it since it's expensive, not always reliable and it won't work with a remote instance or as headless.

Comment: @FlorentB. Those are some fair objections. I personally haven't had too much of an issue with them (my tests are all headed, and the performance loss becomes a micro-optimization when brought up against the the fact that I am running UI tests to begin with). Your welcome to leave your answer as you please, I just thought I'd add an alternative as well.

Comment: I decided to split my text into two Strings and it works fine. Thanks!